# How do I make my website's background image responsive?

Tags: image, web, background

I am new to website development. I need to make the background image of my website responsive. How do I do that? It should be seen well on mobiles as well. Currently, I'm showing the image in my [website](http://goodfoo.me/) as follows:

```html
<img alt="Goodfoo.me" src="http://goodfoo.me/background.jpg"
     id="full-screen-background-image" /> 
<style>
#full-screen-background-image {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  min-width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What is responsiveness? can you explain?

Comment: The image shall adjust itself to the screen size. If the screen size is 1366 x 768 for example, then it should fit the exact screen, and if its 1024 x 768 then it should fit here too.

Comment: and whoever gave it a negative vote .. thanks to you too!

Comment: -1 Maybe also have a look at [why you shouldn't just post a link to your website](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/217025) but rather add the relevant code to the question and add information about what you've allready tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the image to take up the whole width of the screen, simply set `width` instead of `min-width`, [like this](http://phihag.de/2013/so/responsive-img/):

```css
#full-screen-background-image {
  z-index: -999;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without guarantee that it makes sense to do it this way, add the following to your CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

But keep in mind that if you open the page on a *really* big screen, like a tv, it will fail as the image isn't upscaled. If you don't mind the quality loss caused by upscaling, simply remove the `max-` part of the rule. That way the image always fills the container width-wise.

Note that this affects all images on the page.

Comment: That would match all images, which is almost certainly a bad idea. Also, if the screen width exceeds the image width, it would leave an empty space to the right.

Comment: @phihag You are right, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your background picture fit the screen, you can use

```
background-image {
     width: 100%;
}
```

in your css